# Add NAND device to QEMU Stellaris

Tags: arm, qemu

I need to test NAND FTL on QEMU. My NAND controller(Tc6393xb) which is already emulated on QEMU has to be interfaced with ARM Cortex-M3. So I chose stellaris as my base machine. can somebody help me with information on adding this controller(Tc6393xb.c in QEMU 1.2.0) to stellaris. Secondly how do I test it on non-OS environment.

Answer (score 0):

In Qemu version 2.2.1, there is a device (PXA255 Sharp Zaurus) that instantiates the controller Tc6393xb: [tc6393xb_init function](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/qemu+v2.2.1/hw/arm/tosa.c#L235).